# pbuilder and debuild work, but Launchpad fails on downloading tarball

Tags: launchpad, pbuilder

I've searched through all similar questions, but can't see the solution.
I'm building debian packages for a local project. I successfully built it both for `amd64` and `arm64` with `pbuilder` as

```
sudo pbuilder build *.dsc
```

and with `debuild -S` and `debuild  --set-envvar=RDBASE=/rdkit-sys-2.1.3 --set-envvar=DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS=nocheck -j10` too.
With both commands I'm getting `.deb` files which I can copy to the fresh ubuntu container and install with `apt-get install ./file.deb`.
But when I upload the source file to Launchpad it always breaks on downloading Catch2 - the same works perfectly locally

```
Downloading https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/archive/v2.13.8.tar.gz...
CMake Error at Code/cmake/Modules/RDKitUtils.cmake:257 (MESSAGE):
  The md5 checksum for
  /<<PKGBUILDDIR>>/External/catch/v2.13.8.tar.gz is
  incorrect; expected: 3639fb4cb8020de0dcf1fd5addb39418, found:
  d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
```

md5 checksum `d41...` is for an empty file -what is it, it doesn't download properly or puts it into the wrong /another location?

The second error is

```
make[1]: *** [debian/rules:18: override_dh_auto_configure] Error 2
```

which I don't understand. Is it Clang vs gcc compiler? but it works without any issues with `pbuilder`.
I'm trying to solve it for the long time and can't. Wonder if  `/<<PKGBUILDDIR>>/` is messing things up.
All local builds are run in docker containers on Mac.

the build log is
https://launchpadlibrarian.net/641284667/buildlog_ubuntu-focal-arm64.rdkit-sys_2.1.3-1_BUILDING.txt.gz

thank you